# How to convert Java generics into kotlin language generics

Tags: kotlin

How to convert Java generics into kotlin language generics

The java code:

```
public abstract class Request<T, R extends Request> implements Serializable {}
```

But the kotlin code:How to do???

Comment: "public abstract class Request<T, R extends Request> implements Serializable"，how to convert this use kotlin language?

Comment: test this >>> something: String

Comment: What's the question here? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

According to my needs, I finally realized this way.

```
Open abstract class Request < T, out R > (url: String): Serializable where R: Request < T, R > {}
Open class GetRequest < T > (url: String): Request < T, GetRequest < T > (url){
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [the Java-to-Kotlin converter](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Kotlin%20Koans/Introduction/Java%20to%20Kotlin%20conversion/Task.kt) and get

```
abstract class <T, R : Request<*, *>> : Serializable
```

*But* the second `Request` (the one in `extends Request`) is a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) which shouldn't be used in Java and is happily unsupported in Kotlin. Very likely it should be `Request<T, R>` instead; then the translation uses `Request<T, R>` in Kotlin too.

Comment: "This type parameter violates Finite Bound Restriction."

Comment: That's the error compiler throws when you try use two wildcards.
Actually, I am not convenient that there should be `Request<T, R>` - I see some use cases where second type parameter should be in `Request` bounds.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. According to my needs, I finally achieved this.
Open abstract class Request < T, out R > (url: String): Serializable where R: Request < T, R > {}
Open class GetRequest < T > (url: String): Request < T, GetRequest < T > (url){
}

Answer (score 0):

`public abstract class Request<T, R extends Request> implements Serializable {}`

So, we have two generic types. `T`, which can by any type and `R` which have to extends `Request`. But, `Request` still requires two parameters.

In Java it's simpler as generics are not so strict and we can use raw type.

In Kotlin it would be like this:
`abstract class Request<T, R : Request<*, *> : Serializable`, but then we have a error: `This type parameter violates Finite Bound Restriction.` So, we need to specify somehow second type argument.

I am not sure if it is a correct way for your case, but you can do following:

```
abstract class Request<T, R : Request<*, R>> : Serializable {
    abstract val dummy: R
}

class ExampleRequest<T, N> : Request<T, ExampleRequest<T, N>>() {
    override val dummy: ExampleRequest<T, N> get() = this
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I learned some new knowledge from your help. According to my needs, I finally realized this way.
Open abstract class Request < T, out R > (url: String): Serializable where R: Request < T, R > {}
Open class GetRequest < T > (url: String): Request < T, GetRequest < T > (url){
}